# How to include [] in python regex code?

Tags: python-2.7

I am using python 2.7.8 to write a small python code that reads a rule in a form A ==> B by using regex and return it in a form of 'A, B'. 
This is my code:

```
import re

def fixp1(s):
    pattern = re.compile("(?P<g1>([A-Z0-9a-z]|\?)*):(?P<g2>([A-Z0-9a-z]|\?)*)")
    return eval(pattern.sub("('\g<g1>', '\g<g2>')", s))

x = "[ABCD:NP, [PQR:?TAG1]] ==> [XXX:?P]"

def readrule(r):
    r.split("==>")
    return [fixp1(r[0].strip()), fixp1(r[1].strip())]
```

When I test this code:

```
>>> readrule(x)
```

I got the following error message:

```
readrule(y)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File ".../patterns.py", line 12, in readrule
        return [fixp1(r[0].strip()), fixp1(r[1].strip())]
    File ".../patterns.py", line 5, in fixp1
        return eval(pattern.sub("('\g<g1>', '\g<g2>')", s))
    File "<string>", line 1
        [
        ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
>>>
```

I think this problem happened because I couldn't add '[' and ']' in here

```
([A-Z0-9a-z]|\?)
```

If that's right, how to do it? if not; where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `eval` command, the `RegEx`.sub returns a string which is your match with the replacements applied, you cannot evaluate the string. This yields the `SyntaxError` you are seeing.

If you want to include `[]` in your patterns, you need to escape them with `\`:

```
 pattern = re.compile(r'[\[\]0-9]+')
```

would match strings like '[1234]'.

Comment: I need 'eval' as I need the output as a list not a string. But I follow what you said , the results was quite weird:
>>> readrule(x)
readrule(x)
['[', 'A']
>>>

So, it might be not this is my problem.

Comment: That seems to give me r[0] the first character '[' and r[1] the second 'A'. I tried to do 'eval' after separating the rule 

    def readrule(r):
        r.split("==>")
        n = eval(r)
        return [fixp1(n[0].strip()), fixp1(n[1].strip())]

But this gave me another problem (invalid syntax)

Comment: Yes, you'd need to do something like `left, right = r.split('==>')` to get the left and right hand side of the rule.

Comment: Ok, I did some changes an it worked , I changes eval place to the end. 

    def readrule(r):
    n = r.split("==>")
    return [eval(fixp1(n[0].strip())), eval(fixp1(n[1].strip()))]